# C# Maui содержимое Shell пропадает после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: c#, shell, maui

Есть страница-навигатор AppShell:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="CrimeAvtoService.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CrimeAvtoService"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CrimeAvtoService"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar >
        <Tab Title="Map" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MapPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="AnotherMap">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ReviewPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

ReviewPage тоже является Shell страницей с кастомным тайтлом, однако содержимым ContentPage:

```
<Shell x:Class="CrimeAvtoService.ReviewPage"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CrimeAvtoService"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CrimeAvtoService"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Title="Review">

    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ReviewContentPage}"
        Route="ReviewContentPage"/>
</Shell>
```

В самом ReviewContentPage ничего особенного, простая страница. Почему-то после перезагрузки второй страницы она пропадает и больше не появляется, при чем если я гружу сразу ContentPage, а не Shell, то такой проблемы не возникает.

Если не понятно, прикреплю ссылку на видео: https://youtu.be/fZmFZZdrMNY

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что проблема в XAML? Я вот к примеру думаю, что проблема в C# коде, который вы не показали. Также я думаю, что вы костыльно написали код, игнорируя основы основ, игнорируя привязки, игнорируя XAML, где вместо этого всего, вы делаете `StackLayout` в коде, генерируя ему контент, когда должен быть простой массив, привязанный к своему View...